# PHP: $variable == false or !$variable

Tags: php

As in the title of the question - should I use `$variable == false` or `!$variable` when checking the value in some `if`? I know that they're basically doing the same thing and the second version is faster for some reason, but I'm asking about best practices.

There was a similar question here: [Exclamation mark in front of variable - clarification needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029921/exclamation-mark-in-front-of-variable-clarification-needed) but my question is different. I'm aware that both ways are doing the same thing. I'm asking if there's any technical detail or best practice that would make one of them preferable.

Comment: Just preference. Choose one and stick with it. The latter is more concise but a little harder to read, so if you go with that option make sure your variables are well named

Comment: It's more about the readability. Choose the one you like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclamation mark in front of variable - clarification needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029921/exclamation-mark-in-front-of-variable-clarification-needed)

Comment: `$variable===false` is actually best if you're expecting your variable to be a boolean, because when it fails because the variable is a non-boolean (even if it's falsey like the empty string `''`), you will notice the unexpected behavior right away and spot errors early.

Comment: I'd code for readability first. One additional comment is that using ! is much shorter and can help keep your lines under 80 characters long. Especially if the condition body uses a method `if (!$this->longMethodName())`