# PHP If Statement if (!$_POST) - What does !$_POST mean?

Tags: php

PHP If Statement `if (!$_POST)` - What does `!$_POST` mean?

For instance, in some legacy code I'm looking at, the code reads:

```
    <form action="paypalorders.php" method="POST">
         <input type="hidden" name="orderList" value="' . $orderList . '">
         <input type="submit" value="Archive">
    </form>';
if (!$_POST) {
    file_put_contents('/orders.txt', $output_line1);
}
```

I've looked at a bunch of other threads and haven't seen this exact question asked, so I'm trying to find out what it is. I've seen threads that format it like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
```

But not quite the same as what I'm looking for. Is it the same thing, just shorthand? I'm not sure, which is why I'm asking. I've Googled around and looked at a handful of threads and I'm still not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclamation mark in front of variable - clarification needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13029921/exclamation-mark-in-front-of-variable-clarification-needed)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178101/discussion-on-question-by-james-anderson-php-if-statement-if-post-what-do).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` (not) [logical operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) returns `true` if the argument on its right-hand side is not true. It forces the argument to be evaluated as a boolean. In this case, when the `$_POST` array is evaluated as a boolean it will evaluate as `true` if it is not empty and `false` if it is. (See [converting to boolean](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting).)

`if (!$_POST) {` should be a safe way to detect whether or not *anything* is in `$_POST` if you want to do that. `empty` isn't necessary in that case because [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) are always set, and since you aren't referring to a specific key, you don't need to worry about an undefined index notice.

---

I think it's also worth mentioning that if the only point of the check is to see what type of request was sent, it is probably better to just [check the request method directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359047/detecting-request-type-in-php-get-post-put-or-delete), because `!$_POST` does *not* mean the request wasn't a post, since a post request can be empty.

Answer (score 2):

Since $_POST is an array, if it's empty his value is null, so if(!$_POST) would look like this:

```
if(!null){
  //code 
}
```

The following code returns true or false, but the objective of both is the same.

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
  //code
}
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 2):

`(bool)$array` evaluates to `true` if `$array` contains elements, and `false` if it is empty.

Since `$_POST` is an array, `!$_POST` returns `true` if `$_POST` is empty.

Another way to interpret this, you are performing conditional tasks for the case where this page was not reached through a HTTP POST method.

Answer (score 0):

when you cast an array to bool, it will be cast to bool(false) if the array is empty (eg if count($arr)===0), or bool(true) otherwise. `!` casts whatever it's checking to bool. because $_POST always exists, `if (!$_POST) {` and `if(empty($_POST)) {` both do the exact same thing, they check if $_POST is empty. it's not even about being legacy code, this is still perfectly valid for 7.3.0. the difference between the 2 approaches will only become apparent when you're checking variables that `may not exist`, `!$arr` will trow an `Notice: Undefined variable`-error if $arr doesn't exist, `empty($arr)` will not.